# Invalid return, unknown reason

Tags: c#

Trying to solve this kata (actually Codewars task) , but unfortunately it returns invalid output

```
Rgb(255, 255, 255) # returns FFFFFF
Rgb(255, 255, 300) # returns FFFFFF
Rgb(0,0,0) # returns 000000
Rgb(148, 0, 211) # returns 9400D3
```

What I wrote is

```
using System;

public class Kata
{
  public static string Rgb(int r, int g, int b) 
  {
    return String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
  }
}
```

Output ( Codewars test output )

```
  Expected string length 6 but was 7. Strings differ at index 4.
  Expected: "FFFFFF"
  But was:  "FFFF12C"
```

Any advices ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. Code works, the value 300 cannot be expressed in a string with two hex digits and the result FFFF12C is correct. It is incorrect to expect FFFFFF as output

Comment: Out of curiosity... what's a `kata`? Wikipedia tells me it has something to do with karate

Answer (score 4):

The sample input you provide is wrong.  If you run the following line:

```cs
Rgb(255, 255, 300) # returns FFFFFF
```

You'll see your function really returns `FFFF12C`

What the examples are hinting at is the largest value you should accept is 255, any value above that should be treated as if it's 255.

If you change your function to do just that:

```cs
public static string Rgb(int r, int g, int b) 
{
    return String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", Math.Min(r, 255), Math.Min(g, 255), Math.Min(b, 255));
}
```

It will now return `FFFFFF` for the sample data, and treat other values correctly as well.

Comment: shouldn't the method instead expect a byte?  I think its the method signature that is wrong, not how the value 300 is handled

Comment: Then the example wouldn't compile at all.  It might be correct behavior on some level, but I'd assume, given the example, that the goal is to truncate large int values.

Comment: yes, compile time safety...that's a desirable feature

Answer (score 1):

The data type should be a byte, and 300 is not valid.

```
using System;

public class Kata
{
  public static string Rgb(byte r, byte g, byte b) 
  {
    return String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
  }
}
```